# TypeError: x is undefined - JS

Tags: javascript

Im working on webgl app. I have `starsList` array and for some reason, when I run this function:

```
function initTextures() {

        for (i = 0; i < starsList.length; i++) {
            starsList[i].texture = gl.createTexture();
            starsList[i].texture.image = new Image();
            starsList[i].texture.image.onload = function () {
                handleLoadedTexture(starsList[i].texture)
            }
            starsList[i].texture.image.src = starsList[i].name + ".gif"; 
        }   
    }
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: starsList[i] is undefined
handleLoadedTexture(starsList[i].texture)
```

although `starsList[i].texture` defined at the first line in the loop.
any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

When your onload callback is called your `i` is equal to `starsList.length`.

So `starsList[starsList.length]` is undefined.

When you declare your callback

    `starsList[i].texture.image.onload = function () {
        handleLoadedTexture(starsList[i].texture)
    }`

it doesn't copy some specific value of `starsList`. It will just try to find all variables in scope when it been called.

For solution you can bind each onload callback to use specific `i`